# Integrate two sql queries

Tags: sql, merge

I have these two queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c, d, FROM x WHERE b IN (1, 2)

SELECT DISTINCT c, d, FROM y
```

I would now like to merge these queries such that the statement initiated in the first query only includes rows where the c, d combination is in the output resulting from the second query. Any thoughts on how to do this?  My table is large, so efficiency is important.

Comment: Do the tables `x` and `y` contain the same rows?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  You should tag the question with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `exists`?

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c, d
FROM x
WHERE b IN (1, 2) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM y WHERE x.c = y.c and x.d = y.d);
```

When using `exists`, the `select distinct` is only necessary if `x` has duplicate values.  Otherwise it is not necessary.

And, for performance, you want an index on `y(c, d)`.  Also, an index on `x(b, a, c, d)` would also be helpful in most databases.

Note:  The `distinct` is not necessary in the subquery.  In some databases, you can use `in` with composite values as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.a,x.b,x.c,x.d
FROM x
INNER JOIN y ON x.c = y.c
            AND x.d = y.d
WHERE b in (1,2)
```

Regarding efficiency, your indexing will determine how well that performs.

Comment: If efficiency is a consideration, then this is a bad solution.  The `select distinct` in the second query suggests that there are multiple rows with the same value in `y`.  That generates a larger intermediate set, which then must be reduced using `select distinct`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That is a good point.  I was thinking a bit more basic due to the simplicity of the problem